# Python, need to drop columns with null values from a pandas dataframe transferred to numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tuples, multi-index

Imagine this is the database

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

############
### DATA ###
############
TrainingData = { 'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
                'teacher': [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                'doctor': [0,1,0,0,1,0],
                'engineer': [0,0,1,0,0,1],
                'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
                'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
                'date': [1,1,1,2,2,2]}

TestData = {'name': ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
            'teacher': [1,0,0],
            'doctor': [0,1,0],
            'engineer': [0,0,1],
            'age': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
            'weight': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
            'data': [3,3,3]}
# Convert to pandas dataframe
dfTraining = pd.DataFrame(TrainingData)
dfTest = pd.DataFrame(TestData)
# Print
print(dfTraining)
print(dfTest)
```

Train:

```
    name  teacher  doctor  engineer  age  weight  date
0   Alex        1       0         0   27     160     1
1    Ben        0       1         0   32     209     1
2  Marry        0       0         1   78     130     1
3   Alex        1       0         0   27     164     2
4    Ben        0       1         0   32     206     2
5  Marry        0       0         1   78     132     2
```

Test:

```
    name  teacher  doctor  engineer  age  weight  data
0   Alex        1       0         0  NaN     NaN     3
1    Ben        0       1         0  NaN     NaN     3
2  Marry        0       0         1  NaN     NaN     3
```

I changed them to numpy to prepare for ML model:

```
Y=df_train.groupby('name')['weight'].apply(lambda x: (x.to_numpy()))
df_train_x=df_train.drop('weight', axis=1)
X= df_train_x.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: (x.to_numpy()))

K=1

df_test_x=df_test.drop('weight', axis=1)
X_pred_null=df_test_x.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: (x.notnull()))
PresentVariables = (X_pred_null.to_numpy())
```

Now I want exclude null columns from X, but when I use

```
NearestNeighbor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=K).fit(X[:, PresentVariables[0]], Y)
```

It gives following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [23], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 NearestNeighbor = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=K).fit(X[:, PresentVariables[0]], Y)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:906, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    903     key = np.asarray(key, dtype=bool)
    904     return self._get_values(key)
--> 906 return self._get_with(key)

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:921, in Series._get_with(self, key)
    916     raise TypeError(
    917         "Indexing a Series with DataFrame is not "
    918         "supported, use the appropriate DataFrame column"
    919     )
    920 elif isinstance(key, tuple):
--> 921     return self._get_values_tuple(key)
    923 elif not is_list_like(key):
    924     # e.g. scalars that aren't recognized by lib.is_scalar, GH#32684
    925     return self.loc[key]

File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:956, in Series._get_values_tuple(self, key)
    953     return result
    955 if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
--> 956     raise KeyError("key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex")
    958 # If key is contained, would have returned by now
    959 indexer, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key)

KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'
```

The error is for X[:, PresentVariables[0]]
Here I want to drop columns with null values from dataframe transferred to numpy array
Appreciate your help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the df

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor

############
### DATA ###
############
TrainingData = { 'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
                'teacher': [1,0,0,1,0,0],
                'doctor': [0,1,0,0,1,0],
                'engineer': [0,0,1,0,0,1],
                'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
                'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
                'date': [1,1,1,2,2,2]}

TestData = {'name': ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
            'teacher': [1,0,0],
            'doctor': [0,1,0],
            'engineer': [0,0,1],
            'age': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
            'weight': [np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN],
            'data': [3,3,3]}
# Convert to pandas dataframe
df_train = pd.DataFrame(TrainingData)
df_test = pd.DataFrame(TestData)
```

Assign the weight column as target

```
y_train = df_train["weight"]
```

Create x_train by excluding weight and age column.

```
x_train = df_train.drop(["weight", "age"], axis=1)
```

Column name contains string input. convert it to numbers by label encoding

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(x_train["name"])

x_train["name"] = le.transform(x_train["name"])

x_train = x_train.to_numpy()
```

Fit the model

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
neigh = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=2)

neigh.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Apply the same transformation in test as well

```
x_test = df_test.drop(["age", "weight"], axis=1)
x_test["name"] = le.transform(x_test["name"])

x_test = x_test.to_numpy()
```

Run prediction

```
print(neigh.predict(x_test))
```

With respect to the age columns, I dropped it in training as you were trying to drop the null values.

you can retain the age column while training. But impute the age column before predict step (as age column has null values in testing dataframe).

Comment: Thank you, so how about doing the groupby? do you mean if I use label encoding for the name, then I don't need to use groupby?

Comment: Not exactly. It is jut a choice. There are situations where you just feed the raw data and provide more variations to the model. In some case, you collate and give only the necessary information.

So, you can very well do a groupby.  For showing an example , I did a Label Encode. Label encode will not fit on all situations. You may need to see other encodings as well.

Comment: In short, you can do groupby and then encode the data before feeding it to the model.